# How to diff two untracked text files using git command line

Tags: git, command-line, git-diff

Say you have a folder within a git repo that's excluded with a ignore file
a.txt
b.txt

The files are regenerated by an application on the fly and won't ever be included to the repo.
I would like to diff the text between a.txt and b.txt using the git command line for windows. I just have installed git, and I prefer to keep it like that
Is there a command that performs this task?

Thank you

Comment: `git diff --no-index a.txt b.txt`

Comment: @phd that's a better dup.

Answer (score 0):

You can diff two files with git style using

```
git diff --no-index a.txt b.txt
```

No matter where those files are. You don’t even need any repository, just git installed.

If you are using git bash on Windows, you can also use the regular diff command like

```
diff a.txt b.txt
```

Or

```
diff -u a.txt b.txt
```